# What is "Microsoft shadow copy partition" partition used for?

Tags: windows, backup, vss

I have a vm that restored from snapshot and find it cannot boot. compare it with the source vm, there is one extra partition "Microsoft shadow copy partition" created on it.

```
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P Unknown                     2048     616447     614400 [Basic data partition]
 2 P EFI System                616448     819199     202752 [EFI system partition]
 3 P MS LDM MetaData           819200     821247       2048 [LDM metadata partition]
No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
 4 P MS Reserved               821760    1081343     259584 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 4 P MS Reserved               821760    1081343     259584 [Microsoft reserved partition]
 5 P MS LDM Data              1081344  209713118  208631775 [LDM data partition]
 6 P MS LDM Data            209713119  209715166       2048 [LDM data partition]
 7 P Unknown                   821248     821759        512 [Microsoft shadow copy partition]
```

what is this 256k partition used for?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560401(v=vs.85).aspx, IOCTL_DISK_RESET_SNAPSHOT_INFO

> Note A side effect of using this IOCTL is that Disk Management tools
>   may report an additional partition of the type "UNKNOWN" on GPT disks.
>   This 256 kilobyte partition is created by the IOCTL operation and is a
>   snapshot partition used in the restore process. This partition is
>   expected and can be ignored by system administrators.

Comment: It is used by the [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636.aspx)

Comment: Volume Shadow Copy is a service that creates and maintains snapshots (“shadow copies”) of disk volumes in Windows 7 and Vista. It is the back-end of the System Restore feature, which enables you to restore your system files to a previous state in case of a system failure (e.g. after a failed driver or software installation).

Comment: I understand it is used by VSS , what I want to know is under what condition will this partition get created. What kind of information is saved there. It's not always there even you create a application consistent snapshot.